# Issue in reading Chinese language as XML input in sp_xml_preparedocument

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to read Chinese for my Insert Stored procedure, XML reading SP is taking bulk input parameters as XML then parsing/reading it using "sp_xml_preparedocument" and inserting in a table. Problem here is it is reading Chinese as "???" characters.

Below is xml reading SP:

```
    DECLARE @idoc int;
    DECLARE @cnt int = 0;           

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><DocumentElement><Specifications><ID>1</ID><Name>维</Name><Value>123</Value></Specifications><Specifications><ID>2</ID><Name>重量</Name><Value>123123</Value></Specifications></DocumentElement>'

    SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*)
    SELECT  ID, Name, Value
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/DocumentElement/Specifications', 2)
    WITH (ID int, Name nvarchar(MAX), Value nvarchar(MAX))
```

And output is:-

```
   ID    Name     Value

   1     ?    123

   2     ??   123123
```

You can see Name is coming as ??s in-place of Chinese characters. I tried changing XML encoding to UTF-8 and UTF-16, but no luck.

Comment: This could just be an output problem (when you print the result). The number of question marks matches the number of Chinese characters, which would not happen if the encoding was totally off, so I think you get the data correctly. Try to print to a file as UTF-8.

Comment: @Thilo, I have to insert this output in a table, Can you give an example to get this output as UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the XML needs to be defined as Unicode string using `N''`.

Second, SQL Server's XML processing does not allow the `encoding` attribute as it issues an error

> Msg 6602, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 1
>   The error description is 'Switch from current encoding to specified
>   encoding not supported.'.

I guess the argument is that as SQL Server uses UCS-2 for NVARCHAR, there cannot be any other encoding.

Fixing both errors will give you the desired result.

Comment: -1 No, XML does not need to be defined as Unicode. And the variable type must match the encoding. ISO-8859 is a valid encoding and in such a case obviously the variable cannot be Unicode, since Unicode is a different encoding. When handling XML in SQL Server one must be always careful not to mismatch the declared encoding with the actual encoding, but your justification is plain incorrect.

Comment: In *this* *case* the XML needs to be in Unicode, as it contains '维'. Thus you need N'', and thus you cannot have an encoding attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Can you present the document as UTF-16 instead of ISO-8859-1? The following works fine:

```
   DECLARE @xml XML = N'<?xml version="1.0" ?><DocumentElement><Specifications><ID>1</ID><Name>维</Name><Value>123</Value></Specifications><Specifications><ID>2</ID><Name>重量</Name><Value>123123</Value></Specifications></DocumentElement>'

    SELECT  x.value(N'ID[1]', 'int') as ID,
      x.value(N'Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Name,
      x.value(N'Value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
    FROM @xml.nodes (N'/DocumentElement/Specifications') T(x);
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3269).

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the variable as XML solved the issue for me.

The call to sp_xml_preparedocument failed while parsing the character ä of "Käufer garantierte." Setting the encoding as UTF-16 threw an error "Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported." I was passing the XML string as parameter from C# code as NVARCHAR(MAX).